# apt-get update stuck to 0%

Tags: server, apt, internet

I have already tried all of the answers related to this questions, however, nothing seems to solve my issues.

When trying  to update apt or any package it remains stuck to :

```
root@nfs:~# apt-get update 0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com
(91.189.91.23)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26)]
```

My network interfaces :

```
root@nfs:~# ifconfig 
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr
08:00:27:06:48:a0
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe06:48a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18735 (18.7 KB)  TX bytes:53591 (53.5 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:92:98:6c
          inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  sk:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe92:986c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:665 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:101036 (101.0 KB)  TX bytes:62517 (62.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)  TX bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)
```

And my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
root@nfs:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
...
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface auto enp0s3 iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
auto enp0s8 iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

It's been working perfectly until several days ago and all of a sudden, it stopped working. No modification has been made.

I can ping any host on the internet, even google, or us.archive.ubuntu.com :

```
root@nfs:~# ping us.archive.ubuntu.com 
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=159 ms
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=154 ms ^C
--- us.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics --- 
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 154.070/157.008/159.947/2.965 ms 

root@nfs:~# ping www.google.com 
PING www.google.com (172.217.21.68) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from fra07s31-in-f68.1e100.net (172.217.21.68): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=63.7 ms ^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics --- 
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 63.741/63.741/63.741/0.000 ms
```

Most of the answers I saw here and in other places were suggesting to disable IPv6 configuration, which I did and still nothing, however it seems that my configuration is using the IPv4 definiton.

I have the same on 3 different VMs (in virtualbox) which used to work correctly. 
Reinstalled from scratch one of them, the issue persists.

I'm on ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS, connecting to the internet via my host machine's connection, network interface enp0s3

Any ideas please ?

Thanks in advance. 
Vlad

Comment: Have you tried, perhaps, just waiting for a response?  Depending on one of several hundred potential issues, the download could take time.  Especially if you've got VMs in VirtualBox and something on your host computer is using more bandwidth and therefore slowing down access to your computers.  (Ping is only good to determine if your connection is up and can reach outside, it can't reliably work with determining if there's something else slowing things on your network among other problems)

Comment: Yes, I have waited for the past 4 hours. Nothing executing on the host that might consume the bandwidth. I posted the ping results in order to prove that I can get to the internet. Still trying to figure out why I can't update or install any package via apt. I can download packages with wget.

Comment: I have the same problem and no idea how to solve it. I tried different solutions, I am on ubuntu 16.04 on an ARM embedded computer Nvidia TX2